# How does DARTS compare to ENAS?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, search

How does DARTS compare to ENAS? Which one is better or what advantages does they each have?

Links:

- [DARTS: Differentiable Architecture Search](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.09055)
- [Efficient Neural Architecture Search via Parameter Sharing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03268)